# Xamarin iOS app with WKWebView not allowed by Apple

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I already made everything that google says, even some stackoverflow posts... But, Apple does not allow my app. I created a Custom Renderer, but it makes reference to WebView anyway. So, the app is not allowed. Is there someway to use the WKWebView without any references to WebView?

Comment: did you follow ALL of the instructions here?  https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/uiwebview-deprecation-xamarin-forms/

Comment: yes,. In this article he says to put a text that would help the app stop beeing rejected in App Store, but this article is in February the apple's rule started in April, before this it was just a warning. Now it's not allowed anymore to have WebView in new apps. i have no idea how to implement the WKWebView in xamarin.ios without making any reference to WebView, i think this is not possible...

Comment: there are a set of very explicit steps given to fix this.  It is not just "put a text".  Did you follow all of the steps?  A custom render is NOT part of the recommended solution.

Comment: Yes. I already followed this article. The custom render i've made to try to replace the WebView to the WKWebView, but no success.

Comment: You do not need a renderer.  If you are using the correct version of Forms it will automatically use WKWebView.  Unless you have some code that explicitly references UIWebView you should be fine.

Comment: I got a class that inherit WebView. In my app i need to use the WebView to show a webpage that the user will navigate.

Comment: But the webview i can't use, so, i tried it with the renderer

Comment: Why can't you use WebView?  WebView is NOT the problem, UIWebView is what Apple no longer allows.  Xamarin has updated XF so that WebView is rendered as a WKWebView.

Comment: That's weird then. So, why Apple keeps sending the email saying that i need to change it? I already changed what they said. I do not know what else to do.

Comment: Either you have not followed the instructions from Xamarin, or you have a direct reference to UIWebView in your code or in some third party nuget

Comment: and i got the latest version installed.

Comment: I found the solution, i had to add this text in mtouch:--optimize=force-rejected-types-removal

Comment: @GabrielJuren Welcome to SO! If have solved that , remember to share the solution in answer when you have time. It will help others who have similar issue. :-)